# $L^p(T)$ is separable for $1 \le p < \infty$, but $L^\infty(T)$ is not separable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, separable-spaces

**Update:** I understand the separability of $L^p(T)$ now, but I'm unable to prove the non-separability of $L^\infty(T)$. Could someone please provide some more details/hints? Thank you!

---

> Prove that $L^p(T)$ is separable for $1 \le p < \infty$, and $L^\infty(T)$ is not separable.

$T$ is the unit circle in $\mathbb C$, i.e. $T = \{z\in\mathbb C: |z| = 1\}$. We define $L^p(T)$ for $1\le p < \infty$ as the class of all complex, Lebesgue measurable, $2\pi$-periodic functions on $\mathbb R^1$, for which the norm $$\|f\|_p = \left\{\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(t)|^p\, dt \right\}^{1/p}$$ is finite. We define $L^\infty(T)$ similarly.

---

First of all, what metric do we use to talk about **density** here? I assume we're using the metric induced by the $L^p$ norm.

---

**Attempt for $L^p(T)$ with $p\in [1,\infty)$**:
I am trying to explicitly construct a countable dense subset of $L^p(T)$. I have a proposal for a countable dense subset, which I am sure is countable, but I'm unable to show it is dense. In case it is not dense, I would appreciate any other suggestions. I define $$\mathcal C = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal C_n$$ where $$\mathcal C_n = \{f: [-\pi,\pi] \to \mathbb C: f \text{ takes values in }\mathbb Q \text{ on endpoints of } I_{n,k},\\ f \text{ is linear on }I_{n,k}, 0\le k \le n-1, f(\pi) = f(-\pi)\}$$ and $$I_{n,k} = \left[-\pi + \frac{2\pi k}{n} , -\pi + \frac{2\pi (k+1)}{n}\right] \quad (0 \le k \le n-1)$$
Clearly, $$|\mathcal C_n| = |\mathbb Q^n|\quad \text{and} \quad |\mathcal C| = \left|\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb Q^n \right|$$
so $\mathcal C$ is countable. Is it dense too?

---

**Attempt for $L^\infty(T)$**:
How do I get started with showing that $L^\infty(T)$ is not separable? I am trying a proof by contradiction. Suppose $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a countable, dense subset of $L^\infty(T)$ (which can be identified with $L^\infty[-\pi,\pi]$.) The norm on $L^\infty(T)$ would be the essential supremum norm. What's next?

Comment: Better with a counterexample, in my opinion: Consider an uncoutable family $\{U_\alpha\}_\alpha$ family of measurable subsets of $T$, then prove that $$\{\chi_{U_\alpha}\}_{\alpha}$$ is a discrete subspace of $L^\infty$ (where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function for $A$). I think that doing it by contradiction would eventually require to present a counterexample

Comment: I think an easier way of showing that claim would be to use the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. Then you could take the set of polynomials with rational coefficients, which would be dense in the continuous functions. However, the continuous functions are dense in $L^2$ (approximate by simple functions, then approximate indicator function by indicator function of open set and this one you can easily approximate by a continuous function).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Are you suggesting the following? (1) Polynomials on $[-\pi,\pi]$ with rational coefficients are dense in all polynomials on $[-\pi,\pi]$, since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$. (2) Polynomials on $[-\pi, \pi]$ are dense in $C(T)$. (2) $C(T)$ is dense in $L^p(T)$. By (1), (2) and (3), the set of all polynomials on $[-\pi,\pi]$ with rational coefficients is dense in $L^p(T)$. Here, (2) is a consequence of Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: Also, what "metric" are we using when talking about "density"? In (1) and (2) it seems to be the sup-metric, but in (3) it seems to be the metric induced by the $L^p$ norm. Won't that be a problem? We might want all the three metrics to be the same, I suppose.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor the measure space has finite measure, so you have an inequality of the form $\|\cdot\|_p\leq C\|\cdot\|_\infty$ that will handle the problem

Comment: For showing $L^\infty$ is not dense, you can also prove by observation that $\{\chi_{[0,\theta]}\mid\theta\in(0,1)\}$ is uncountable, but for each distinct $\theta_1,\theta_2\in(0,1)$, $\|\chi_{[0,\theta_1]}-\chi_{[0,\theta_2]}\|_{L^\infty}=1$.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor - yes you're right

Comment: @epsilon-emperor Indeed that is what I suggest. We take always the $L^p$ metric. Note that convergence in sup-norm implies convergence in $L^p$ for finite measure spaces.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Could you explain why, and how it helps?

Comment: $\| f \|_p \leq \left ( \int_X \| f \|_\infty^p d \mu \right )^{1/p}=\mu(X)^{1/p} \| f \|_\infty$. As for why this helps, the point is that given $f \in L^p$ you have $\| p - f \|_p = \| p - g + g - f \|_p \leq \| p - g \|_p + \| g - f \|_p$ where $g \in C(T)$ and $p$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients. You control the first term using Weierstrass and the inequality I stated at the start. You control the second term using the density of continuous functions in $L^p$.

Comment: @epsilon-emperor I think Ian covered the topic, don't you agree? :)

Comment: @Ian Thank you. Stone-Weierstrass gives density w.r.t. the sup-metric, but I see now that the inequality you proved at the start of your comment carries that density over to the metric induced by the $L^p$ norm, for any $p\in [1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $L^{\infty}(T).$

Let $(b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of members of $[0,2\pi)$ with $b_1=0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=2\pi.$

For any $g\in \{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ that is, any $g:\Bbb N\to \{0,1\},$ and for any $t\in [0,2\pi)$ let $f_g(t)=2g(n)$ if $t\in [b_n,b_{n+1}).$ For unequal $g_1,g_2\in \{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ we have $\|f_{g_1}-f_{g_2}\|_{\infty}\ge 2.$

So the family $F= \{B_{\infty}(f_g,1):g\in\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}\}$, of non-empty open balls of radius $1$, is pairwise-disjoint and has cardinal $|F|=|\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}|=2^{\aleph_0}.$

If $D$ is dense in $L^{\infty}(T)$ then $D$ must intersect each member of $F$, implying $|D|\ge |F|.$

Comment: Topological cardinal functions are cardinals associated with a topological space $S$. The weight $w(S)$ is the least infinite cardinal $k$ such that $S$ has a base (basis) $B$ with $|B|\le k.$ The density $d(S)$ is the least infinite cardinal $k'$ such that $S$ has a dense subset $D$ with $|D|\le k'.$ The cellularity $c(S)$ is the least infinite cardinal $k''$ such that if $F$ is any discrete open family in $S$ then $|F|\le k''$. (A discrete open family in $S$ is a set of pairwise-disjoint open subsets of $S$, a.k.a. an open cellular family). We always have $w(S)\ge d(S)\ge c(S).$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short proof for $p \in [1,\infty)$:

Note $C([0,1]) \subset L^p([0,1])$ is dense and separable. Let $A \subset C([0,1])$ be the countable dense subset. Fix $f \in L^p([0,1])$, then there exists a $g \in C([0,1])$ such that for any $\epsilon >0$,

$$\vert \vert g - f \vert \vert_p < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Furthermore, as $C([0,1])$ is separable in the uniform norm, there exists some $h \in A$ such that

$$\vert \vert h - g \vert \vert_\infty < \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$

Observe then that

\begin{align}
\vert \vert h - g \vert \vert_p&=\bigg(\int \vert h - g \vert^p\bigg)^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
&\leq (m([0,1])\vert \vert h - g \vert \vert_\infty^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
&=\vert \vert h - g \vert \vert_\infty.
\end{align}

Thus by triangle inequality,

\begin{align}
\vert \vert h - f \vert \vert_p &\leq \vert \vert h - g \vert \vert_p + \vert \vert g - f \vert \vert_p\\
&<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
&=\epsilon.
\end{align}
As $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, $A$ is dense in $L^p$.